# Humanities Research with Professors as a High Schooler?

Tags: united-states, email, supervision

I am a high school student (legally old enough to work) looking for opportunities to work with professors in political theory. The way research is done is quite different from many folks in STEM, so how could I be of use to a professor while deepening my own passion for the field?

COVID has definitely restricted travel, but I won’t have limitations when it comes to being geographically closer to professors I’m working with (living near a major international airport, free schedule during breaks).

Comment: I did some googling ("opportunities for high school students in political science"), and came up with this for example: https://www.highland-k12.org/site/handlers/filedownload.ashx?moduleinstanceid=295&dataid=941&FileName=political%20science%20summer%20programs.pdf   I would guess that trying to participate in some organized program would be a better bet than asking individual professors to supervise you.

Comment: Do you live near a university that teaches the subject you are interested in? Large or small.

Comment: @Buffy Yes, I live close to a large state university. However, I may be away from home this summer in another major city (East Coast) so I'm trying to see how to go about contacting professors there.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest that you contact, first by email, some professors at the universities, both the local one and another where you will be co-located. Explain something about your interest, but also why you think you have enough background to make a relationship interesting to them.

A local professor might be more help and you might be able to work through a secondary school instructor to make the contact.

But, I think you will have a hard job to convince anyone without some support from somewhere. Interest isn't enough. If you are widely read in political theory it will help.

I worry, of course, that if you are merely driven by the current political situation and have "opinions" about it, then you won't be successful. So, examine your motivation. Political theory is about theory and only incidentally about "politics" as popularly understood.

Have you read Plato's Republic, for example? Anything by John Locke? If you have some of that background then you might have a chance of success.

Answer (score 0):

#### Maybe, if the university offers a summer internship program.

I would recommend focusing on your high school studies, but I applaud your desire for learning. Some universities might offer summer internships to allow undergraduate or high school students to work with their postgrad students; if the university you're interested in offers a program like that, feel free to apply for it if you qualify for its requirements.

Otherwise, I would simply state that professors are very busy people whose time is quite valuable, and if helping you isn't a part of their job, then they may not be interested in adding you to their responsibilities without a suitable monetary incentive (e.g. businesses paying a sizable amount of money to get research done on their products).

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted; summer internships are by far the most likely way for high schoolers to get engaged.